# Make sliding table above on Experince Builder on ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-experience-builder

So ESRI is moving out of Web AppBuilder and I'm remaking apps on Experience Builder.
I'm facing difficulties to make sliding table with all sheets, so viewers can view data, when they want it.

How do I make sliding table above on Experince Builder on ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 0):

When I want a sliding table in Experience builder, I use a [Sidebar widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/experience-builder/latest/configure-widgets/sidebar-widget.htm).
This widget has two default containers. You can choose a dock side. For example in the first container I insert a Map widget and in the second container I insert a [Table widget](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/experience-builder/latest/configure-widgets/table-widget.htm).
In a table widget (card Content - section Arrangement style) you can choose how to organize all your sheets (at first select the data source for a layer - card Content).